# Ngrx advantages over Observable Data Services architecture?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, flux, ngrx-store

Both observable data service and Ngrx store provides a Store based solution for angular applications.

Ngrx uses the flux design pattern and requires a 3rd party library, in contrast of Observable data services which can be implemented with built in features of angular and rxjs and is in a way i guess is an angular design pattern by it self.

information regarding Observable Data Service architecture can be found [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/)

I have read his article : [Redux, RxJs and Ngrx Store - When to Use a Store And Why?](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/)
to really understand what are the main problems that store based solution aim to solve , and the way i see it they both solve these main problems :

- solves the Facebook counter problem which happened because of multiple actors changing the same data concurrently
- the "extraneous props issue" when moving an input way down/up the component tree when only the bottom/top one really needs it (useless to all the components in the way - breaking SRP)

i see a cost when using Ngrx - the bundle size is bigger , plenty boiler plate code - for a simple feature need to change multiple files and impl an action , a reducer, if using ngrx side effects then also a loader action and error action..
the learning curve of understanding the concept and the way flux works is bigger then observable data services i guess..

one advantage however is the awesome dev tools it provides.

So the question is as the title states : 
**Ngrx advantages over Observable Data Services architecture ?**

a simple Todos observable data service store example :

```
 @Injectable()
    export class TodoStore {

    private _todos: BehaviorSubject<List<Todo>> = new BehaviorSubject(List([]));

    constructor(private todoBackendService: TodoBackendService) {
        this.loadInitialData();
    }

    get todos() {
        return asObservable(this._todos);
    }

    loadInitialData() {
        this.todoBackendService.getAllTodos()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    let todos = (<Object[]>res.json()).map((todo: any) =>
                        new Todo({id:todo.id, description:todo.description,completed: todo.completed}));

                    this._todos.next(List(todos));
                },
                err => console.log("Error retrieving Todos")
            );

    }

    addTodo(newTodo:Todo):Observable {

        let obs = this.todoBackendService.saveTodo(newTodo);

        obs.subscribe(
                res => {
                    this._todos.next(this._todos.getValue().push(newTodo));
                });

        return obs;
    }

    toggleTodo(toggled:Todo): Observable {
        let obs: Observable = this.todoBackendService.toggleTodo(toggled);

        obs.subscribe(
            res => {
                let todos = this._todos.getValue();
                let index = todos.findIndex((todo: Todo) => todo.id === toggled.id);
                let todo:Todo = todos.get(index);
                this._todos.next(todos.set(index, new Todo({id:toggled.id, description:toggled.description, completed:!toggled.completed}) ));
            }
        );

        return obs;
    }


    deleteTodo(deleted:Todo): Observable {
        let obs: Observable = this.todoBackendService.deleteTodo(deleted);

        obs.subscribe(
                res => {
                    let todos: List<Todo> = this._todos.getValue();
                    let index = todos.findIndex((todo) => todo.id === deleted.id);
                    this._todos.next(todos.delete(index));

                }
            );

        return obs;
    }


}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: As the title states - what are the advantges of using Ngrx in contrast of Observable Data services..

Comment: You're asking about advantages/disadvantages, which means you are asking for opinions (whether you think it or not), which is off-topic on SO. You *seem* to favor Observable Data Services (my opinion), so go with that. Try *ngrx* at some point, and form your own opinion. Then you can go with what works for your application.

Comment: @R.Richards I agree im asking for opinions - i would like to hear what other people think and how they favor Ngrx that could help me make the best architectural decision , is it not appropriate to ask these types of questions ?

Comment: It's considered off-topic to ask for opinions on SO. It just opens things for debate, rather than helping someone solve a programming issue. This is one of those topics that, depending one the person, could yield many different answers.

Comment: You can't win by picking either. Next week there will be a new popular library that everyone starts using and you'll want to switch to that. If you wait for the best tool that gives you the best architectural design, then you'll be waiting a long time. Ngrx is a paradigm that you must follow, and you'll either be glad or mad that you followed it. Try both ways and go with what feels best for you personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance differences:

- One single store for all state. Your example looks like you'd have one per kind of data: todo, events, contacts, etc. If you only have one kind of data then NgRx may be overkill.
- Time travel debugging. Love this feature!

You could google `benefits of ngrx` and see additional responses.

Comment: yes in my example ill have a store for each domain model in my app - same as ngrx that has a state for each of the apps domain models (or atleast most of the times), lets say in my app i have multiple kinds of data - why is a single store  for all the states is an advantage ? and regarding the debugging i totally agree

Comment: Everyone on the team knows the one and only one place to get the data.

Comment: I cant see difference in distinguishing where the data came from because in the case of Observable Data Services : the team needs to know which service has the data , and in case of Ngrx the team needs to know which state has the data (in other words which selector to use), therefore i don`t think there is an advantage in that regard..

Comment: Tons of boilerplate for "cool debug tool", yeah.

Comment: This may also be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omnwu_etHTY "You might not need NgRx" talk by one of the developers of NgRx.